# Linear Algebra: Question on if this proof can conclude this way, or not.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

Let $E$ be a vector space, and let $P \in L(E,E)$ (where $L(E,E)$ is the set of linear maps that map $E$ to $E$) such that $P^2=P$.

Prove that $E= span \{kerP \cup ranP\}$ and conclude that there exists a unique pair of vectors $y,z \in E$ with $y \in kerP, z \in ranP$ and $x=y+z$.

---

Proof:

Suppose $x = y+z$ with $y \in kerP, z \in ranP$.

Then $Px=Py+Pz=Pz$.

$=P^2w=Pw=z$ ${  }$ (because: $z \in ranP$, there exists $w \in E$ where $z = Pw$) .

Hence, $Px=z$.

So, $x = y + z = y + Px$, showing that $x$ is in the span of the kernel and range.

My question is: Does this also prove uniqueness? Why or why not? Do I have to go the extra step and suppose that x has two other elements in the range and kernel, respectively, and show that they, in fact, equal the original $y$ and $z$?

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, one needs to show that the decomposition is unique. This follows canonically from the fact that you have a direct sum,  i.e. $(\ker P)\cap (\text{ran}\,P)=\{0\}$.
- Your argument is not really a proof, because it doesn't show that $y$ exists. The natural way to show that every $x$ admits the required decomposition is to write $$x=(I-P)x+Px.$$